# Show file names in file input programmatically with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, file

Good night,

I am developing an application with Angular15, and one of the functions is to populate a table that contains data of members of a team.

To add a member, a button is clicked and a modal window is displayed to fill in the data and add some files. To edit, it is the same operation.

I have been able to save the data and upload the files to a server folder, but when editing I am having a problem: In the file inputs, the name of the uploaded file does not appear, giving the appearance of that nothing has been uploaded, although it really has been uploaded.

I am storing the name of the document in a member attribute, and I am binding the file input to the member attribute using ngModel.

The input gets a "No file selected" message, and if I try to programmatically set the file name on the input(which I control on the .ts with a ViewChild and ElementRef), I get the following error:

> core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string. Error: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

It is totally logical that I cannot do this operation due to the security risk it entails, but I don't want to insert a file programmatically, I just want to show the name, without its content. Is there any way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In [<input type="file">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) web docs

> You cannot set the value of a file picker from a script — doing something like the following has no effect:

```
const input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
input.value = "foo";
```